# How to reference a local gem from a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I need to reference a local gem from a plain ruby script, without installing the gem. On the trail of [How to refer a local gem in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444827/how-to-refer-a-local-gem-in-ruby), i tried creating a Gemfile with the following setup:

```
%w(
  custom_gem
  another_custom_gem
).each do |dependency|
  gem dependency, :path => File.expand_path("../../#{dependency}", __FILE__)
end
```

and the script looks like this:

```
require 'custom_gem'
CustomGem::Do.something
```

When I execute this with:

```
bundle exec ruby script.rb
```

I get:

```
script.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- custom_gem (LoadError) from script.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

If I leave out the  `require 'custom_gem'` , I get:

```
script.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant CustomGem (NameError)
```

I even tried without bundler, and just writing `gem ... :path =>̣ ...` in the script itself, but without results. Is there any other way of referencing custom gems from ruby scripts, without installing the gems locally?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure that your gem name as same as in Gemfile (e.g. `custom_gem`)

```
# Gemfile

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "custom_gem", path: "/home/username/path/to/custom_gem"
```

Don't forget to actually install this gem using bundler

```
bundle install
```

After that, the script should be ready to use by `bundle exec ruby script.rb`

```
# script.rb

require 'custom_gem'
CustomGem::Do.something
```

Comment: Yep, had a spelling error, required something other than the gem in the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without using a Gemfile, you can install a local version of a gem by running `bundle exec rake install` in the gem's root directory and then you can reference it just like any other installed gem.