# Require local gem ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem that I created in Ruby on my local machine and I need to require this gem in a plain Ruby script that starts a service.

I have to require like this:

```
require_relative '../../../my-gem/lib/my/gem'
```

Is it possible to do this require without putting in the relative path?

Comment: Is it in your gem path folder? Did you install it somehow or it just sits in a random folder?

Comment: I installed the gem with rake install, I just checked and my gem appears in /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems

Comment: And doesn't a simple `require 'yourgem'` works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a local gem from a ruby script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549963/how-to-reference-a-local-gem-from-a-ruby-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` checks for files in `$LOAD_PATH`. You can put your gem in one of those directories in order to `require` it directly. If you don't like your load path, you can add a new directory to it in your script, or set the `RUBYLIB` environment variable which is added to the load path.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a gem, you can install it and set the version you want (in my example 1.0.0.beta) with `gem 'my-gem', '= 1.0.0.beta'`.

But I think yu look for another solution:

You can extend the location where `require` looks:

```
$:.unshift('../../../my-gem/lib')
require('my/gem')
```

or

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift('../../../my-gem/lib')
require('my/gem')
```

You could also use `$: << '../../../my-gem/lib'`, but I prefer `unshift`. If your gem contains a file with similar names as in a gem (avoid it!), then `unshift` guarantees your script is loaded.

Comment: where should I put the unshift?

Comment: In your code before the `require`. See my code examples.